# How to detect properly value modifications on a PropertyGrid (MFC)?

Tags: mfc, propertygrid

I've been developing a program in MFC which fills a PropertyGrid with some data located in a database of mine.
One of the fields from this PropertyGrid contains data related to a person's age. Here's the implementation:

```
 CMFCPropertyGridProperty * pProp = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Age"),    (variant_t)PropAge->GetNext(headAge), _T("This is a description"));
 pProp->EnableSpinControl(TRUE, 0, 150);
 pGroup->AddSubItem(pProp);
```

Where `PropAge` is a `CList` containing the `age (integer) of each person's register`.

Here's my problem: when I try to modify it's value (using the SpinControl or typing another value), the new value does not appear with the bold font. Moreover, when I use the method `IsModified()`, it returns false:

```
void CPropertiesWnd::DoSomething()
{
    CMFCPropertyGridProperty * PropSel;
    PropSel = m_wndPropList.GetCurSel();
    bool a = PropSel->GetSubItem(1)->IsModified(); //SubItem containing the Age data.
                                                   //Returns False when it's modified!
                                                   //It always returns 'false', even if
                                                  //there was made a modification.  
}
```

I used the Debugger to check what was going on and saw something really interesting:

http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/8256/c90j.jpg

(Note: `m_VarValue` represents the current value and `m_VarValueOrig` represents que value before the modification)

as you can see, there is a type difference between the variables `m_VarValue` and `m_VarValueOrig`. (What does I4 mean?)

I also noted that there are other subitems on this project that also deal with numbers, and they actually show when
a modification was made. Their implementation is something like this:

```
 pProp = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Something"), (_variant_t) 0l, _T(""));
```

What does this 'l' right after the 0 means? Does it have something to do with the I4 type?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The solution is actually really simple: instead of using a `(variant_t)` in the second argument on the creation of the pointer to a new PropertyGridProperty, a `(long)` casting should be used in order to detect properly a modification on the SubItem:

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty * pProp = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Age"), (long)PropAge->GetNext(headAge), _T("This is a description"));
```